# If A,B,C,D are angles of a quadrilateral and $\sin (A/2)\sin (B/2)\sin (C/2)\sin (D/2)=1/4 $ prove that $A=B=C=D=\pi/2 $

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

If A,B,C,D are angles of a quadrilateral and $\sin (A/2)\sin (B/2)\sin (C/2)\sin (D/2)=1/4 $ prove that $A=B=C=D=\pi/2 $.

How should I proceed? Any suggestions might be helpful.Thanks.

Comment: No.Its not.Why?  @N.S.JOHN

Comment: Thought I saw it.

Comment: It's from arihant trigonometry book

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use AM-GM and [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen's_inequality):
$$\sqrt[4]{\sin (A/2)\sin (B/2)\sin (C/2)\sin (D/2)}\le \frac{\sin (A/2)+\sin (B/2)+\sin (C/2)+\sin (D/2)}{4}\le$$
 $$\le\sin \left(\frac{A/2+B/2+C/2+D/2}4\right)=\sin 45^{\circ}=\frac1{\sqrt2}$$
Then $$\sin (A/2)\sin (B/2)\sin (C/2)\sin (D/2)\le \frac14$$

$$\sin (A/2)\sin (B/2)\sin (C/2)\sin (D/2)= \frac14 \Leftrightarrow \sin (A/2)=\sin (B/2)=\sin (C/2)=\sin (D/2)\Leftrightarrow $$
$$\Leftrightarrow \frac A2=\frac B2=\frac C2=\frac D2=\frac {\pi}4 \Leftrightarrow$$
$$\Leftrightarrow A=B=C=D=\frac {\pi}2$$